# How can i store the particular data type of the json response object in an array (ex: of numbers) to pass in datasource as variable

Tags: json, angular, typescript

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title: String = "Heatmap";
  
    constructor(private app:AppServiceService) { }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.app.getdata().subscribe
        (
            (response)=>{console.log(response)}       
        )
    }
   

    dataSource: Object []= [
    [1, this.num.value, 9, 23, 0, 39, 0],
    [0, 18, 37, 0, 0, 50, 0]
    
    ];
    
 
    
   
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the type somewhere in your app, for example in your service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";

export interface GetDataResponse {
    data: number[]
}


@Injectable()
export class AppService {
    public getData(): Observable<GetDataResponse> {
        return of({ data: [1, 2, 3, 4] });
    }
}
```

Then use it in your subscribe parameter:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getData().subscribe((response: GetDataResponse) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
  }
```

If the response has a simple type, you can just use it directly:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getData().subscribe((response: {data: number[]}) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
}
```